# Is it possible to change the color of a word in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, text

I have a regular texbox control. I need to highlight some words with a red color. Is it any possible to do with JavaScript (jquery or anything else)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most rich text javascript editors use an `iframe` with `designMode='on'` since that yields the best cross browser results:

```
<iframe ID="rtbox"></iframe>
```

To make the `iframe` editable and insert rich text via Javascript you can use the following sample code:

```
var rtbox = document.getElementById('rtbox');
var doc = rtbox.document ? rtbox.document : rtbox.contentDocument;
doc.designMode = 'on';
doc.body.innerHTML = 'one <span style="color:red">red</span> word';
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that.  Your only way would be to use a rich text editor component like FCKEditor or similar.

Comment: Well, technically you can as all those controls do is to use Javascript on a TextArea element and so forth.

Comment: rubbish. they are richtext controls. this is a completely different beast to a textarea.

Comment: @SpliFF, so how does TinyMCE work then?  Have a look at the example here http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php.  It's just a textarea control and a big pile of java script.

Comment: Tinymce inserts an iframe dynamically and hides the textarea. Use firebug/firefox to see the actual content of a the example and search for 'content_ifr'

Comment: SpliFF is 100% correct: A textbox cannot contain child elements ergo it cannot style individual substrings. End of.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use different styles in a standard `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using TinyMCE for a rich text editor.

And no, what you say is not possible on a normat textarea.